# How to mock a class that belongs to a module dependency? (And ensure that certain method inside the mocked class has been called) Jest - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock the `S3` class inside the `aws-sdk` module while macking sure that the methods inside the class `S3` can be spyed.

I am able to mock the `S3` class inside `aws-sdk` however I cannot spy the methods inside the class.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

These are my code snippets:

`services/s3.js`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const uploadAsset = async (param) => {
    try {
        const response = await s3.upload(param).promise();
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

module.exports = { uploadAsset }
```

`services.s3.test.js`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { uploadAsset } = require('../services/s3')

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
    return {
        S3: class {
            constructor() { }
            upload(param) { //  I want to make sure that this method is called        
            return {
                    promise: () => {
                        return Promise.resolve(
                            {
                                Location: `http://${param.Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${param.Key}`,
                                Key: param.Key
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


describe('uploadAsset() functionality', () => {
        it('should upload an asset', async () => {
            const uploadPath = 'users/profilePicture';
            const base64Str = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/';
            const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Str, 'base64');
            
            const s3 = new AWS.S3();

            const response = await uploadAsset({
                Bucket: 'BucketName,
                Key: `KeyName`,
                Body: buffer,
            });

            const spy = jest.spyOn(s3, 'deleteObject')

            expect(spy).toBeCalled(); //  This spy nevers gets called
        });
    });
```

Any insights would be helpful.

Thanks.

I mocked the `aws-sdk` successfully. However my spy in the `S3` never gets called.

I am almost positive that this is a scope problem. I think my spyOn method only affects my local `S3` class instance. However I still have no idea how to test this specific case scenario.